# Loading a block from a controller in magento, cache issue?

Tags: php, magento, controller, block

I have two methods inside my controller i call to get html for various ajax updates.

```
    protected function _getDemoShippingMethodsHtml()
    {
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_demoshippingmethod');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();

        return $output;
    }

    protected function _getSelectedDealerHtml()
    {
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_selecteddealer');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();

        return $output;
    }
```

During one request to my controller if i call only one of these methods it loads the block as expected. The problem comes in where i try to call both of these function during one request. Which ever method is called first outputs the expected html, and the second method call outputs the exact same html as the first.

Answer (score 0):

In your block class that is used create an empty pseudo-constructor
protected function _construct() {}

Answer (score -1):

try use clean cache programatically 
Mage::app()->cleanCache();

[Clear Magento cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701456/clear-magento-cache)